# How to avoid powershell prompt message while copying data

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-blob-storage

How can I avoid this confirmation message while copying data in another blob? Using –Confirm overwriting file but I don’t want to overwrite just want to ignore if file existing already and move next.

Message from powershell:
Confirm
Are you sure to overwrite 'https://destinationblob111.blob.core.windows.net/container1/file1.doc'?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

### code i m using is below

$BlobCopy = Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -SrcContainer $ContainerName -SrcBlob $BlobName -DestContext $DestStorageContext -DestContainer $ContainerName -DestBlob $BlobName -Confirm
       $BlobCpyAry += $BlobCopy

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to overwrite the destination blob, you might can check if the destination blob existing, and only copy when it doesn't exist.

If you want to overwrite, add -Force can overwrite the destination blob.